# Convergence and divergence at an end point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it possible for a series to converge at some given end point $x = A$ and at the same time the differentiated series to diverge at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, $x^n$ on $[0,1]$ converges for $x=1$ but $nx^{n-1}$ diverges for $x=1$.

Comment: this is what I am talking about, right on!

Comment: I don't see how the former series is convergent at x=1